# Child component not refreshing when updating data from Parent Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

I  am using a util lwc data table and passing list of records from the parent component, I am using a refresh button to re-fetch the records from Apex (imperatively) and update the LWC data table but the LWC data table is not updating records in data table.

Util LWC Data table Template :

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-spread slds-scrollable_x"> 
            <div class="slds-col slds-scrollable_x" style={tablewidth} >
                    <lightning-datatable
                        key-field="Id"
                        columns={columns}
                        data={recordsToDisplay}
                        hide-checkbox-column
                        default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                        sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                        sorted-by={sortedBy}
                        onsort={onHandleSort}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                        class="slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_top "
                        >
                </lightning-datatable>            
            </div>
        </div>
```

Button on Child Util LWC data table :

```
<lightning-button  title="refresh records" icon-name="utility:refresh" icon-position="center" onclick={handleRefresh} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

Child Data table JS :

```
handleRefresh(event){
    this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('refreshrecords', {detail:event.detail}));
}
```

Parent HTML :

```
<c-util-lwc-datatable 
            columns={ordercolumns}
            records={allorders}
            onactionclicked={handleselectedorder}
            show-search-box={showsearchbox}
            total-records={totalRecords}
            onrefreshrecords={handlerefreshrecords}
            >
</c-util-lwc-datatable>
```

JS :

```
handlerefreshrecords(event){
    this.handleGetOrders();
}

handleGetOrders(){
    getAllOrders({accountId: this.recordId})
    .then((result) =>{
        this.allorders = result.map(row=>{
            return{...row, opportunityName: '/' + row.Id, Orders: row.Order_Id__c}
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
        this.allorders = undefined;     
    })
}
```

Even though ***this.allorders*** is coming back with new data, Child LWC data table is not being update with new data. I do not have a `@wire` method to use refreshApex.

***How can I make sure the child LWC gets new data and data table renders with new data?***

Comment: @CasparHarmer can you give an example how? Because I am not using a `for:each`, how would I add key and how can I use it?

Comment: @CasparHarmer I am not using forEach here, it's only Data table where I am using a Key but it doesnt seem to work. On the side, I am trying it to see if I can use Wire method.

Comment: is getAllOrders apex method cacheable?

Comment: @glls no, it is not. When I log the new order response, I do get updated orders list, just the LWC is not re-rendering with new values.

Comment: what does your c-util-lwc-datatable  template look like?

Comment: @glls I updated the question with it.

Comment: @glls while I was trying to convert imperative apex to Wire method, I had to set the Apex method as `cacheable=true`

Comment: @CasparHarmer as far as I. was aware, `@track` is not required anymore since all variables are reactive by default. Also, `@track` does not work, I have tried that too. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: @CasparHarmer Oh, I see, let me try. I was trying to add Wire method to see if that works but getting error even after adding cacheable-true on apex method.

Comment: @CasparHarmer no luck with that too, this is just very weird. I have no idea why the data table wont refresh.

Comment: Added a new answer that I have verified works (using accounts)

Answer (score 0):

I built and tested my own version that I have verified to work (on Accounts)

Child HTML:

```
<template>
  <lightning-button  title="refresh records" icon-name="utility:refresh" icon-position="center" onclick={handleRefresh} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>

  <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-spread slds-scrollable_x"> 
    <div class="slds-col slds-scrollable_x" >
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                columns={columns}
                data={records}
                class="slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_top ">
        </lightning-datatable>            
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Child JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

const COLUMNS = [
  { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
  { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website', type: 'url' },
  { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone' }
];

export default class LwcTestTable extends LightningElement {

  columns = COLUMNS;
  @api records;

  handleRefresh(event){
    this.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('refreshrecords', {detail:event.detail}));
  }

}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  >
        <c-lwc-test-table
            records={allaccounts}
            onrefreshrecords={handlerefreshrecords} >
        </c-lwc-test-table>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Parent JS:

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/TestClass.getAccounts";

export default class LwcTester extends LightningElement {

  @track allaccounts = []

  connectedCallback(){
    this.handleGetAccounts();
  }

  handlerefreshrecords(event) {
    this.handleGetAccounts();
  }

  handleGetAccounts() {
    getAccounts({})
      .then((result) => {
        this.allaccounts = result.map(row => {return { ...row }});
      })
      .catch((error) => {this.allaccounts = undefined;})
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have a key field in the Util LWC Data table set as Id, the line `return` I have is only to add a hyperlink for Opportunity Name in the data table. how do I add Id and which ID should it be?

Comment: I am extending lightning-data-table, that is what my util is and I have `key-field="Id"` in my util lwc. So that in the return, I just set `row.Id` for every row (allOrders), but that is not refreshing the lwc.

Comment: plus, I dont really have for-each here.

Comment: I literally have same one, it's still not working, no idea why.

Comment: Try testing in Aura - make an aura app and include this component and run in the dev console. That's how I ran mine. At least you'd know then that it was limited to some profile/sharing/permissions thing.

Comment: It's definitely not sharing because, what I am able to see the records in console.log and I do see the updated array come to `allorders` in your case `this.allaccounts`. If I delete a record, it goes away when I try to refresh it. The only thing is that the data table is not being updated.

Comment: I figured out one problem, which I overlooked in my util component. I do not directly assign the `record` variable to the dataTable. I actually have pagination and search so I have other variable which are dependent on records variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getter for the orders, now it should work fine.
One time I also face something similar so it worked for me by using getter because getters being called on the change of data everytime and it will also create the new reference so it will work

```
@track orders = [];
 handlerefreshrecords(event){
        this.handleGetOrders();
    }
    
handleGetOrders(){
    getAllOrders({accountId: this.recordId})
    .then((result) =>{
        this.orders = result.map(row=>{
            return{...row, opportunityName: '/' + row.Id, Orders: row.Order_Id__c}
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.error = error;
        this.allorders = undefined;     
    })
}

get allorders (){
    return [...this.orders];
}
```